# Is it possible to have a fixed size array as a unordered_map key

Tags: c++

I am wondering if it is possible to have a `std::unordered_map` use a fixed size array as a key. For example, here is a simple cache that holds strings as the value but needs a `uint8_t[]` as the key:

```cpp
using UserKeyV1 = uint8_t[16];
using UserKeyV2 = uint8_t[32];

template <typename T>
class StringCache
{
   public:
      bool addString(const T &userKey, const std::string &value)
      {
         auto [it, result] = m_cache.try_emplace(userKey, value);
         // ^^^^^^^ this line won't compile: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal

      }
   private:
      struct EqualToFn {
        bool operator()(const T &left, const T &right) const {
            return std::memcmp(&left[0],
                               &right[0],
                               sizeof(T)) == 0;
        }
      };

      struct HashFn {
        size_t operator()(const T &k) const {
            return std::_Hash_impl::hash(k);
        }
      };

      std::unordered_map<T, std::string, HashFn, EqualToFn> cache_;
}
```

And in use would be something like:

```
StringCache<UserKey1> cache1;

uint8_t uniqueKey[16];  // this key was provided by 3rd party lib
cache1.addString(uniqueKey, strUsername)
```

This won't compile due to the error listed above but I'm not sure why. I created the custom hasher and equality functions for the array so that it knew how to handle such a key. I could probably solve this with `std::array` and copy the key to it first but wanted to avoid that if possible as it would involve a copy and this code will be potentially called 1000s of times a second.

Is what I am trying to achieve possible or do I just use std::array as a key?

Comment: How about using std::array<uint8_t, 32> as a key?

Comment: *Is what I am trying to achieve possible or do I just use std::array as a key?* -- Maybe you should also specify what the high-level problem is that you're trying to solve.  Maybe your "solution" is not the way to approach the problem.

Comment: If you want performance, `std::unordered_map` is a bad choice. Watch this talk about better hash maps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2fKMP47slQ&t=4187s

Comment: What copies are you concerned `std::array` may perform? The map is going to have to store the whole array of values. Maybe you want `std::vector` with move semantics instead, though you're trading smaller copies when moving versus always requiring dynamic allocations when defining the map's keys.

Comment: If unordered_map support heterogenous lookups, this would be fairly trivial, as you could store keys of type `std::array<uint8_t, 16>` and also lookup in the map with a `uint8_t[16]`. If performance of copying 16 bytes is a serious concern, you shouldn't using `unordered_map`

Comment: I'm happy enough to use the std::array as a key but 1) Wondered why i couldn't use the array as I had coded it and 2) if i can save a 16 or 32 byte copy 10k a second surely that must be a good thing? Ultimately, the end goal was to write a LRU so the unordered_map seemed best fit from what I have been reading.

Comment: The question (aside the performance concern) is if the arrays are going to outlive the hashtable (them being global variables suggests that, as well as the fact that you're trying to avoid copies, however I cannot see it clearly stated). Should that be the case, can't you just use a reference to and array as key, say:     `unordered_map<reference_wrapper<char[4]>, unsigned, HashFn>`?

Comment: The arrays won't outlive the table unfortunately. The code I posted was just a short snippet to help explain my question. The real code doesn't have global variable and the arrays are provided by a 3rd party that will go out of scope after saving to the cache.

Answer (score 0):

it works fine with std::array

```
  #include <cstdlib>                                                                 
  #include <iostream>                                                                
  #include <unordered_map>                                                           
  #include <cstring>                                                                 
  #include <array>                                                                   
                                                                                     
  using UserKeyV1 = std::array<unsigned char,16>;                                    
                                                                                     
  template <typename T>                                                              
  class StringCache                                                                  
  {                                                                                  
     public:                                                                         
        bool addString(const T &userKey, const std::string &value)                   
        {                                                                            
           auto [it, result] = m_cache.try_emplace(userKey, value);                  
           // ^^^^^^^ this line won't compile: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal
           return result;                                                         
                                                                                  
        }                                                                         
     private:                                                                        
        struct EqualToFn {                                                           
          bool operator()(const T &left, const T &right) const {                     
              return std::memcmp(&left[0],                                           
                                 &right[0],                                          
                                 sizeof(T)) == 0;                                    
          }                                                                          
        };                                                                           
                                                                                     
        struct HashFn {                                                              
          size_t operator()(const T &k) const {                                      
              return std::_Hash_impl::hash(k);                                       
          }                                                                          
        };                                                                           
                                                                                     
        std::unordered_map<T, std::string, HashFn, EqualToFn> m_cache;               
  };                                                                                 
                                                                                     
  int main()                                                                         
  {                                                                                  
      StringCache<UserKeyV1> cache1;                                                 
                                                                                     
      //uint8_t uniqueKey[16];  // this key was provided by 3rd party lib            
      UserKeyV1 uniqueKey;                                                           
      std::string strUsername = "username";                                          
      cache1.addString(uniqueKey, strUsername);                                      
  }
```

Comment: The question says *"I could probably solve this with std::array and copy the key to it first but wanted to avoid that if possible"*.

Comment: as all the genius didn't noticed while moving down my answer, the user asked a solution without copying values

Answer (score -1):

I think if you want to avoid copy you can just use std::string_view class, the code becomes simpler.

```
  #include <unordered_map>                                                           
  #include <string_view>                                                             

  using UserKeyV1 = std::string_view;                                                
                                                                                     
  template <typename T>                                                              
  class StringCache                                                                  
  {                                                                                  
     public:                                                                         
        bool addString(const T &userKey, const std::string &value)                   
        {                                                                            
           auto [it, result] = m_cache.try_emplace(userKey, value);                  
           return result;                                                            
                                                                                     
        }                                                                            
                                                                        
        std::unordered_map<T, std::string> m_cache;                                  
  };                                                                                 
                                                                                     
  int main()                                                                         
  {                                                                                  
      StringCache<UserKeyV1> cache1;                                                 
                                                                                     
      uint8_t uniqueKey[16];  // this key was provided by 3rd party lib              
      std::string strUsername = "username";                                          
                                                                                     
                                                                                     
      cache1.addString(std::string_view{(const char*)uniqueKey, sizeof(uniqueKey)}, strUsername);
  }
```

for c++20 you can probably use std::span, or to implement your own wrapper for earlier standards.

Comment: try to run this code : https://pastebin.com/grCLaXVj and look how something goes wrong

Comment: string_view internally copies address and size of memory, in this case you are storing string_view that pointing to not owned memory

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper in your example that I see by your link, you pass string to function by value and create string_view to this local string. When function is finished, local variable is destroyed and string_view. You can pass string to function add_string by reference to avoid this issue. The question was how to avoid copying of array, string view solves this problem

Comment: I think you have to warning about the fact that he need to store the original uniquekey to dont make string_view to point to an non existing object

Answer (score -2):

I think the best way of doing this (without copying the value as you requested) would be to calculate an hash using the uint8_t[16] array and use the hash as key. You can choose one among the many hashing algorithms already existing (xxhash, md5, sha32, crc32 etc...).
The best match with your case would be crc32.

Any of these usually takes a `const void*` and a `size_t` to calculate the memory hash, you can pass your key address and size without copying it as you requested.

An example would be to use crc32 hash (basically an uint32_t) and to use it as key for the unordered_map.

So you can still keep your class, by adding one line in your example.

```
StringCache<uint32_t> cache1;
uint8_t uniqueKey[16];
cache1.addString(GetArrayHash(uniqueKey), strUsername);
```

You can't use this solution if you need to get back the **uint8_t[16]** from your cache. Based on your class code you posted there are no uses of the actual key value.

Note: an unordered_map with uint32_t as key will use an identify function as hash algorithm, in short by using crc32 hashing you are probably not losing efficiency but this is not guaranteed by the standard since it does not define exactly which algorithm to use to hash an array of uint8_t (but the msvc and gcc implementations I have been able to test use crc32).

using this approach you can definitely remove your HashFn and EqualToFn to your StringCache class.

```
template <typename T>
class StringCache
{
   public:
      bool addString(const T &userKey, const std::string &value)
      {
         auto [it, result] = m_cache.try_emplace(userKey, value);
      }
   private:
      std::unordered_map<T, std::string> cache_;
}
```

Comment: the user asked for a solution without copying the value.

Comment: You can't use an unordered_map with a key type that doesn't support an assignment.
So i propose to solve it changing the key type. Using uint32_t as key type the code user posted will compile

Comment: (my downvote is removed) You should maybe give an example of what `StringCache` would look like.

Comment: yeah thank you i will add it asap

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper and what are you going to do if hash collision happens?

Comment: unordered_map is an hash map, internally it already use crc32 or other hashing algorithm. When you are going to choice an hash algorithm or you are going to choice to use or no an hash algorithm you always need to know what are your needs, what are the best matches with your needs. In case of high chance of conflict you can't use hashing, this is true for any case usage of hashing.